pg_class_row with JOIN and composition object
I would like to know if the row factory functionality supports the creation of composite objects using the JOIN clause. For example.
Python class
class Profile:

    id: int | None = None
    nome: str | None = None
    permissions: list[bool] | None = None


class User:

    id: int | None = None
    name: str | None = None
    profile_id: int | None = None
    profile: Profile | None = None

How could I make it so that fatchone() to return a User object like:
User(
    1,
    "Any User Name",
    1,
    Profile(
        1,
        "Any Profile Name",
        [false, false, true]
    )
)

I am passing the User class to the pg_class_row(User) function.
Pseudo tables
Table profiles:
id serial,
nome varchar(20)
permissions boolean[]

Table users:
id serial,
name varchar(50)
profile_id integer FK(profiles.id), 

